# facebook connect does not clear session cookie on logout

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm doing some integration with Facebook on a project (using graph api) and everything was working fine until now I discovered that facebook doesn't clear my session when I click on the logout url. I'm doing logout through php, not javascript, so the logout url looks like:

```
https://www.facebook.com/logout.php?next=url&access_token=token
```

After clicking on that link the user is logged out on facebook, but the session still exists on my website. To actually clear the session I have to refresh the page one more time after clicking that url. This is a strange behavior, in my opinion.

What you guys think of this? I tried even to personally remove the facebook cookie, but it is still there, and it is cleared only after I hit the refresh button on my browser.

p.s. to get the facebook session I do something like this:

```
My_Facebook_Helper::instance()->getSession(); //it should be === null if it doesn't exist
```

p.p.s. it could be a bug? i don't remember having this issue about a week ago when I first started to implement this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is registered as a bug. Please add your own repro to this bug to help get it fixed

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/250825644953332

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this bug and realized it wasn't that the session wasn't being cleared, but if you have offline access, it will automatically get you a new session.

Comment: This is not the case since I don't have offline_access :)

Answer (score 1):

Try finding the `formatData` function somewhere at `LoginWindow` (AS3) and find this line:

```
vars.redirect_uri = FacebookURLDefaults.LOGIN_SUCCESS_URL
```

Change the value for 'http://www.facebook.com/' and logout from that html page when logged in.

This is a temporary solution to logout if you are developer, not the end user.

Answer (score 0):

I have just a solved a simular problem today.
Try using this to get your session:

```
$session = $facebook->getSession();
```

And this could also help for the logout url:

```
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array('next' => $url, 'session_key' => $session['session_key']));
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: nope, the session it's still there and i need to refresh the page to disappear :). but thanks for your answer!

Comment: So after you refresh the session is gone? Well if so, make it refresh after automatically. A little more detail could help! Good luck! :)

Comment: yes...i kinda did a workaround to solve this after all, removing the session myself if some conditions are met :) thanks!

Comment: That's ok. Facebook PHP SDK isn't the easiest to work with. :)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this

```
$logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(array('next' => 'some url', 'session_key' => $session_key)) . 'session_key=null';
```